# Issue displaying spinner image on button click

Tags: jquery

I have a button on click of which i intend to display a spinner image

```
$("#btnSearch").bind('click', function () {
    if (lookupSearchValidation()) {
        $(this).toggle();

        //spiness image to display
        $("#loading").show();

        //method to populate the grid
        LoadLookUpSearchGrid();
    }
});
```

but the image  displays after the grid populates

Comment: `$("#loading").show();` write this before `if`

Comment: @anup this will then show before `lookupsearchvalidation` may be OP wants only when validation passes

Comment: $("#loading").show(); having it before wont make a difference as it will only display after all the statements execute including method to load the grid

Answer (score 1):

if i missunderstand you, then sorry!

```
$("#btnSearch").bind('click', function () {
    if (lookupSearchValidation()) {
        $(this).toggle();

        //spiness image to display
        $("#loading").show("fast",function(){
            //method to populate the grid
            LoadLookUpSearchGrid();
        });


    }
});
```

Comment: glad that i could help

Comment: $("#loading").show("fast",function(){
                loadSearchGrid($("#txtValue").val());
               });      why i am getting text value "txtValue" null

Comment: @user3193626, my answer depends on your question how to show loading indicator. BUT why textvalue is null is a new question and should be asked in a new question